# Are all storage devices divided into sectors?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems

I have read that a hard disk is divided into regions called sectors (a sector can be for example 512 bytes in size).

And that a file system will arrange groups of sectors into blocks (a block can consist for example of 8 sectors) and when Linux writes a file to the hard disk, it actually writes to these blocks and not to the sectors.

Now my question is, are all storage devices (for example: USB drive, CD, DVD, etc.) divided into sectors, or is it just hard disks?

Answer (score 5):

No.  There are numerous storage devices that dont use sectors, such as [punch cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card).

[image: Punch card]

As you can see there are no sectors here.

No real reason to add this answer, other than I wanted to put a picture of a punch card.  :)

Answer (score 4):

> Are all storage devices divided into sectors?

No.
One of the oldest storage media is tape (magnetic, paper, mylar), and data is not written to tape in sectors.

Sectors are an intrinsic and salient property of hard disks.
Since most modern storage peripherals emulate a HDD at the ATA interface level (in order to gain faster acceptance by users), you as a user might think that these other peripherals actually have sectors also.
At the ATA interface, there certainly is the concept of a sector.

But NAND flash memory, which is the underlying storage device in SSDs, USB flash drives, and SD cards, is organized in pages and blocks, and do not have sectors.
Users might refer to NAND flash pages as "sectors", but the various NAND chip datasheets I've looked at (e.g. [Micron](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO-pbQpKnaAhUD34MKHS28Cv4QFghRMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fe2e.ti.com%2Fcfs-file%2F__key%2Fcommunityserver-discussions-components-files%2F639%2F3005.MT29F1G08ABBEAH4E.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0grW_tcyq6B9icFtVjwZO2), [Numonyx](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnxqS5nqnaAhVC44MKHTpcB_4QFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.micron.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2Fdocuments%2Fproducts%2Fdata-sheet%2Fnor-flash%2Fparallel%2Fp33%2F208034_p33_65nm_sbc_64m_128m_discrete_ds.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0YpqNLHQ0BNr7l8zSaHyW6)) did not even contain the word "sector".
Of course there could be another NAND flash chip out there that does use the "sector" terminology for familiarity (like wikipedia).

From a Micron datasheet:

> • Organization
>    – Page size x8: 2112 bytes (2048 + 64 bytes)
>    – Page size x16: 1056 words (1024 + 32 words)
>    – Block size: 64 pages (128K + 4K bytes)
>    – Device size: 1Gb: 1024 blocks
>
> The NAND Flash memory array is programmed and read using page-based
>   operations and is erased using block-based operations.

Comment: Some tape drives do have a concept of block size...

Comment: @rackandboneman -- Yes.  A long time ago I wrote programs to write/read records and multiple records packed in blocks for 7 & 9-track magnetic tape.  But tape records/blocks are not addressable, whereas hard disk sectors have an address property.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all storage devices are divided into sectors.

Most are 512 bytes
Some new large drives are 4096
CD-ROM are 2048

A few manufacturers have custom storage for specialty storage needs, but most do not.  Most of these devices only have a few KB or a couple MB of storage meant for internal usage.

Even then the amount of work it takes to "make your own filesystem" is high enough that most just use someone else's file system.  If they want to block the user from messing with it they encrypt it.

The "sector" is simply a way to divide up an amount of storage so the people writing file systems and other infrastructure have a common base to work with.  Also the entirety of storage can't be loaded into ram all at once so it has to be sub-divided.

If sectors were allowed to be **any** size the people writing file systems would have to handle all possible values making there job that much harder.  The harder it is the more room for human error and the greater the chance something goes horribly wrong and you lose your data.

Also optimizing for performance would also be much harder as people who choose exceptionally low number like 2 bytes would always have terrible performance.

Comment: Hmm. Tape Drives?

Answer (score 0):

#### Are all storage devices divided into sectors?

No.

Random access storage devices *may* be divided into sectors, it depends on the device driver.

Linear access storage devices (for example Tape Drives) will not be divided into sectors.

Comment: That's wrong in this generality, for example [DEC tapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECtape) had blocks, and worked pretty much like floppies on early PCs.

Comment: @dirkt A block is not a sector.

Comment: *"it depends on the device driver"* -- The device itself will be the determining factor.  Tape does not have sectors.  But tape is a sequential access media, and not a random access media.  Never heard of *"linear access"*, and I was around when there was still Teletypes and paper tape.

Comment: @sawdust Tapes can be rewound to access particular files. That was why I stated linear access rather than sequential access. I was also around when paper tapes, teletypes  and punch cards were commonly used. I wrote my first program (nim) on a teletype :)

Comment: @sawdust [The Linear Tape File System](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1914426)

Comment: That's pea counting, by that definition any unit of storage that's not on some disc-shaped medium is not a sector. In particular, USB drives wouldn't have sectors, even if they look exactly like discs on the USB levels. The question is about mass storage where data is only accessible in certain smallest units of fixed size (whether you call those units sectors or not) vs. mass storage where data can be accessed in other ways.