# Pendrive or SD card partition at specific place

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, sd-card

Usually Windows places first partition at 2048 sector. However I encountered different other places for which I need to ask you:

1. Why manufacturers usually place partition in different places? (sectors: 2048, 65536, 131072) What are the engineering decisions that the partition will be in a specific place? Is it that the memory blocks in pendrives or on SD cards are of some specific size?
2. If I place partition in different sector than manufacturer - do I correctly see lower write speed? If yes, is it because there are memory blocks on card/pendrive with specific boundaries?

Comment: https://pawitp.medium.com/block-alignment-on-sd-cards-cf09dca42439

Comment: Asking why a manufacturer does things in a certain way, is asking for speculations and opinions. A foresee the question being closed because of this. To avoid you may want to edit your question.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen There are two questions asked. None of speculations or opinions - these are engineering decisions that manufacturers made which I am asking about.

Comment: Okay, have it your way you'll see ..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The question is briefly answered here:

https://pawitp.medium.com/block-alignment-on-sd-cards-cf09dca42439

Cite:

I find this intriguing since as a computer user, I’ve always seen SD card as a raw storage device where it stores bytes and you can put any kind of data and any kind of file system on it. This is a compliment to the abstraction layer that works so well that I have never bothered to look under the hood as to how SD cards work.

After more research, I’ve found out that the SD Card Association actually specifies the standard file system to use with SD card, and it’s not just “use FAT32” but actually specifies how the file system should be aligned on the card.

It appears that, starting from SDHC, you can only write to the SD card in sectors of 512 bytes, so you cannot just write one byte, you have to tell the SD card the entire sector (512 bytes) you want to replace the content with. If you want to write just one byte, you have to read the 512 bytes, change one byte in memory, then write back the entire 512 bytes.

FAT32 file system also have cluster size. This means that each 4 KB sector on the disk is assigned to only one file (of course, a file can span multiple sectors) so as long as you write only to that sector, you do not have to worry about accidentally overwriting other files. According to Microsoft, for most partition sizes, the cluster size is 4 KB, which fits exactly into 8 SD card sectors.

So when writing a cluster, you can just directly issue write commands to 8 sectors.

When you want to write to cluster 1000, you can just write to sector 8000–8007 without caring about the data previously in those sectors.
Now what happens when you create a partition without being aware of the idiosyncrasy of the underlying storage. Most likely the cluster on the file system does not match the sector on the SD card. This results in the cluster spanning 9 sectors instead of 8.

In unaligned writes, you have to treat sector 8000 and 8008 specially.
In the above example, you would need to issue a read command to sector 8000 and 8008 in order to partially overwrite them (you need to preserve the first part of sector 8000 and the last part of sector 8008 since have data from different clusters). So in the end, you need to read 2 sectors and write 9 sectors, which is less efficient.

In the grand scheme of things, computers have a lot of memory to be used to caching these data and files generally span multiple continuous clusters, so the problem is less severe. If you need to write one cluster, it’s 11 commands instead of 8 (37% more commands). But if you need to write 1000 continuous clusters (e.g. a 4 MB file), it’s 8003 commands instead of 8000 (0.037% more commands), so the problem is not that serious.

However, if you’re on a micro-controller with limited memory and code storage space, then this becomes more of an issue. Not only will you need additional memory to cache data for writing, but your code will be more complex as it needs to handle the case.

If it’s specified that the FAT32 file system on SD cards must have clusters aligning to the sectors of SD cards, your code can simply ignore this edge case and refuse to work with improperly formatted SD cards. Thus, I can see why the SD Card Association wants to specify the file system up until this level.

Answer (score 1):

Ī̲ will not address the point 1. in depth because presumption that manufacturers *should* place the first partition at the same offset is not substantiated. They could market devices for different purposes, after all.

As for the point 2., an important thing is not the partition offset itself, but resulting layout of the filesystem. Most modern solid-state devices [use 4096-byte physical sectors](https://superuser.com/a/1394257/485250), although pretend that the sector size is 512 bytes. In this case, you obviously can noticeably degrade performance by, for examples:

- using filesystem block size smaller than 4096 bytes,
- placing block boundaries at offsets not multiple of 4096 bytes (that is, eight “logical sectors”).

The latter possibility will certainly be achieved if you make a Unix-style filesystem starting from an offset (in “logical sectors”) other than a multiple of 8. AFAIK NTFS uses a data layout concept similar to Unix filesystems (such as ext2/3/4 and UFS), which is not the case for FAT. For FAT, placing the starting sector at offset divisible by 8 does not guarantee a correct layout of so named *clusters*, so special care must be taken.

Comment: You talk about SSD drives, question is about pendrives and SD cards. Nothing about the questions asked.

Comment: I suspect that there are blocks of memory that's why the partitions are differently placed. Just need to know for sure.

Comment: Pendrives and SD cards *are* solid-state devices, answer is largely correct, it is about aligning with physical boundaries. Solid state drives typically need to write per page.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen please put that into separate answer so I could vote for it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen SD cards and pendrives - not all - became SSD memory type, but they weren't before SSD drives came in. I am asking about old-fashion memory in SD cards and pendrives.

Comment: This is nonsense AFAIK. They're all NAND based.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen is it the same as in SSD drives then?

Comment: Essentially yes, however controller / firmware in SD Cards, USB flash drives etc. is less complex than in SSD's. But if we for example consider a CF type memory card, you basically dealing with a SATA SSD. The most ideal offset to the first cluster of the data area is 131072 bytes (1 MiB) as it will always align regardless the page size (512 bytes, 4096, 8192, etc.). In many file systems 1 sectors of file system = 1st cluster, in FAT based file systems it isn't. In (ex)FAT(32) FS, boot sector + reserved + sectors per FAT (* FAT copies) will land you at first sector data area.